# How to diagonalize Lagrangian with two gauge vector fields?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, field-theory, vector-fields

I have recently stumbled upon a Lagrangian i had never seen before. Given two real vector fields $A_\mu$ with force tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ and $V_\mu$ with $G_{\mu\nu}$.
The theory that describes their behavior is:
$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{4}G^{\mu\nu}G_{\mu\nu}+\frac{1}{2}M^2V_{\mu}V^{\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{2}F^{\mu\nu}G_{\mu\nu}$$
I can see how this could be transformed into a free theory without the awful "propagator mix" term $$\mathcal{L}_I=\frac{\lambda}{2}F^{\mu\nu}G_{\mu\nu}  = \lambda   \,A^\mu(-g_{\mu\nu} \Box  + \partial_\mu\partial_\nu ) V^\nu$$which changes between $A$ and $V$. Unfortunately I am not getting how the exact form of the transformation needed to get to the result is obtained. I have tried to rotate the fields $A$ and $V$ with an abstract angle $\theta$ but the condition for which the $\lambda$ term vanishes is awful and another mixed term pops out of the mass term. Furthermore, if I was to go with the theory as it is, the feynman rule for this one would have been A-----><----- V where >< would be $\lambda (g_{\mu\nu}p^2 - p^\mu p^\nu)$, I just can't see how this enters the propagator since any on shell amplitude, I think, would violate energy conservation.

Comment: You can rotate, but it may happen that the mixing angle is momentum dependent so nonlocal. Just diagonalize in momentum space. In general diagonalization may be weird. Better just compute the inverse of the kinetic matrix and work with the three AA, VV and AV propagators that are going to simple ( up to gauge invariance issues). Punchline is that inverse of M is easier than the diagonalizing matrix.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. So I would just have three propagators $\propto \frac{1}{p^2}$ for three kinds of internal lines and no, non trivial, vertices basically